# How to connect my rx480

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I have an Xfx rx 480 gpu. In the box there is a cable with two female 6 pins to 1 male 8 pin. And my card requires a single 8 pin adapter. Should I plug the cable from my psu to both the 6pin female ports?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adaptor is supplied in case your PSU doesn't have a native 8 pin connector. If it does, connect it directly. If it doesn't, connect two 6 pin connectors to the adaptor, then connect the adaptor to the card.

Comment: My psu does have a 6+2 pin and I have it plugged directly into the gpu. So I guess I'm using it the right way this adapter is not needed? Reason I am asking is because from the first time my gpu doesn't work in the first pcie slot (x16) of the mobo, but it does work perfectly in the x4 slot. I thought maybe this was why

Comment: What motherboard are you using?

Comment: Msi b150 gaming m3

Comment: The manual says that any of the slots should work at x16 if only one of them is occupied (but that you should use the first one if you can). The first one should be working too, and if it's not, then it seems more like a motherboard problem, not a problem with the PSU.

Comment: Yes, I just tried pretty much everything, that's why I ask about the power. My only option now is to send them for a warranty service

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to supply power to both 6 Pins to supply the wattage that card needs.